# Issue with Propel Criteria::IN

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I'm trying as add following condition in my query

```
AND momento_distribution.MOMENTO_IDMEMBER IN ( 5, 1, 3, 10, 11, 12, 18, 32, 51, 6 )
```

For that, I'm having following code

```
$friendCsv=Friend::getFriendIdAsCsv($member); //returning string 5, 1, 3, 10, 11, 12, 18, 32, 51, 6
//code
$c->add(MomentoDistributionPeer::MOMENTO_IDMEMBER, $friendCsv, Criteria::IN);
```

Query is failing because it is generating

```
AND momento_distribution.MOMENTO_IDMEMBER IN ( '5, 1, 3, 10, 11, 12, 18, 32, 51, 6' )
```

Adding a single quote on string. If I remove that single quote manually, query runs successfully.

IS there any way to force propel not to put single quotes in values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try that

```
$friendCsv=Friend::getFriendIdAsCsv($member); //returning string 5, 1, 3, 10, 11, 12, 18, 32, 51, 6
$friendArr=  explode(',', $friendCsv);
//code
$c->add(MomentoDistributionPeer::MOMENTO_IDMEMBER, $friendArr, Criteria::IN);
```

Criteria::IN should be used with array not CSV.

Comment: I would say: not a string (instead of *not CSV*)

Comment: Thanks @J0k, YP. Now I'm doing blunders due to deadline pressure. I read that in Jobeet tutorial but still I did it by not thinking on output of pre-existing method. Anyway, thanks to both of you. Stackoverflow rescued me again. On completion of my project, I must give some credit to Stackoverflow and specially j0k.